# Invalid recent display name

Tags: bug, profile-page, display-names

I've recently joined [the Game Development community](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour) and noticed, that there is one recent display name available in my profile:

> [image: Profile]

> [image: Wrong recent name]

I never had such a display name on that site.

BTW, the number in the username, 2147482262, is 1386 less than 2^31 (max value for 32-bit signed int plus 1).

If the "-" counts, then -2147482262 is 2147485034 as an unsigned 32-bit number, 0x8000056A.

Comment: User signup is a mysterious process with strange fail cases and self-healing properties ... probably status-bydesign.

Comment: I joined ja.so 13 days ago and guess what: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIKM1.png On sites I joined earlier (4 moths ago I joined retrocomputing.se) I don't have other displaynames.

Comment: The dash is also an oddity, normally that's not there for auto-generated usernames, so the number used to generate that username is probably negative.

Comment: Rene's is "user-2147482643" (1005 different from 2^31) and [the user ID is 10542](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/10542/rene). The 32 bit unsigned value for -2147482643 is 2147484653, 0x800003ED.

Comment: @rene recent names showed only for 90 days period. According to the [tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67f6E.png).

Comment: Ah, that explains why I don't see that everywhere

Comment: Umm... Fairly sure I saw this come up on MSO 6-8 somethings ago...

Comment: Same here. After associating my account on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com got a "recently used" name of *user-2147482330*.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387233/broken-top-network-post-link-and-title (contains -2147482643)